# adding `noeledmac' when loading `ledmac'

Tags: reledmac, ledmac

I am working on an input file that includes
\usepackage{ledmac}
When I run xelatex I get this message:
"Using package `ledmac' is deprecated. We suggest using`reledmac' instead. If you want to continue with `ledmac', you can disable this message by adding the option`noeledmac' when loading `ledmac'."
My very basic question is:
How do I add the option 'noledmac'?
Where do I write 'noledmac'??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is explained "adding the option". So it is a package option:

replace

```
\usepackage{ledmac}
```

to

```
\usepackage[noeledmac]{ledmac}
```

Note that if you are starting a new project, it is strongest encouraged to use reledmac instead of ledmac.